# Get All Array Values have more than 100 or more, and get array all values 100 with less

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My scenario is i have an multidimensional array and i want to get separated array from multidimensional array.
Ex:- First array return which is all values have 100 or more that key and value return as a separated and Second if array has one value less than 100 and other values have a 100 and more that array key and value return as a separated see below example,

```
Array(
  [124] => Array
    (
        [0] => 140
        [1] => 101
        [2] => 107
        [3] => 116
        [4] => 100
    ) 
)
Array(
  [164] => Array
    (
        [0] => 108
        [1] => 111
        [2] => 124
        [3] => 87
        [4] => 278
   ) 
)
Array(
  [162] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 79
        [2] => 3
    )
)
```

And output should be like this,

```
Array(
  [164] => Array
    (
        [0] => 108
        [1] => 111
        [2] => 124
        [3] => 87
        [4] => 278
   ) 
)
Array(
   [162] => Array
   (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 79
        [2] => 3
   )
)
```

Comment: In your input example, you have three arrays, and your output example has the same exact first two array with the third one missing. I don't understand the logic of how the input maps to the output. Your question also has some important typos that I'm hesitant to correct because their meaning could go in different directions, can you correct those? Lastly, have to tried anything?

Comment: @chr I just wanted to get array with all values has 100 and more and all values with less than value with 100 and more.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Actually i want to exclude that type of array which is all values has 100 and 100 more, and i need to output like get array which is all values check and return if that array 3 values have 100 and more and 1 value has less than 100.

Comment: You want to exclude all inner arrays that have every values less than 100? Is that what you are trying to say? So the first array _is not_ excluded because it has at least one value above 100. Similarly, the second array _is not_ excluded, because even though it has a value less than 100, at least one is above 100. Finally, for the third array, all values are below 100 so it should be excluded. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @ChrisHaas My requirement is in the multidimensional array check all array values and return that key and values which is 3 values have a 100 and 100 more and 2 values have 100 less so that keys and values i want from multidimensional array and check if array has all values 100 and 100 more that key and values exclude from multidimensional array so finally array should be does not have all values 100 and 100 more, but in the multidimensional array found sub array has 5 values but out of 5, 3 values have 100 and more and 2 values have less than 100 values so that key and value array i want.

Comment: @ChrisHaas See my updated question output should be like this part...Thanks.

Comment: What now? You want to filter all subarrays with at least one value below 100. I take that from the expected result. If not, expand your example so that it becomes clear.

Comment: @jspit I want to get array which all values does not have 100 and 100 more, but in this scenario if array has 2 values 100 and 100 more and 2 values 100 less so that array i want return from multidimensional array.

Comment: What sense does the 2nd condition make? If the array has at least 3 values, then there are always 2 values ​​below 100 or 2 values ​​above 100.
Please add an array to the example where the 2nd condition does not apply.

Comment: This can be solved with the function array_filter(). It is customary to show your own attempt at a solution here. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: @jspit See below my question which i have tried before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with array_filter() and a function filter100(). For explanations of the filter function, see the comments there.

```
$data = [
  124 => [140,101,107,116,100],
  164 => [108,111,124,87,278],
  162 => [6,79,3],
  170 => [6],
  171 => [45,34],
  172 => [45,134],
];


function filter100($subArr){
  $limit = 100;
  if(min($subArr) >= $limit) return false;  //all values >= 100
  $count = count($subArr);
  if($count >= 3) return true;  //2 values < 100 or 2 values >= 100
  //from here on only arrays with 0.1 or 2 values
  if($count < 2 OR max($subArr) >= $limit) return false;
  return true;
}


$newData = array_filter($data,'filter100');

//test output
echo '<pre>', var_export($newData,true);
```

Output:

```
array (
  164 => 
  array (
    0 => 108,
    1 => 111,
    2 => 124,
    3 => 87,
    4 => 278,
  ),
  162 => 
  array (
    0 => 6,
    1 => 79,
    2 => 3,
  ),
  171 => 
  array (
    0 => 45,
    1 => 34,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you save my time, i am trying to 4 to 5 hours but did not get exact solution but now it works as i wanted array that array returned.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   foreach ($total_progress as $key => $value) { 
       foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
          if($value1 > 100 ){
            unset($total_progress[$key]);
          }
       }
    }
```

I have tried with this code but it is removed all the 100 and 100 more values from array and return only 100 less value array. but i want to get array which is 100 and more with 100 less values.
So final output should be like this

```
Array(
   [164] => Array
   (
      [0] => 108
      [1] => 111
      [2] => 124
      [3] => 87
      [4] => 278
   )
   [170] => Array
   (
      [0] => 63
      [1] => 100
      [2] => 45
      [3] => 133
      [4] => 243
      [5] => 170
   )  
 )
```

Comment: Ok as an approach. Does not do the job as I understand it. Try your approach with my test data.